# write an add attribute method in objective C

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsmutableattributedstring

Hi I am having troubles to write an custom method for adding attributes for NSMutableAttributeString by passing strings, int, and colour as parameters, I am getting three errors below, please help..

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString*)setAttributedSuits: (NSString*) suitString
                                   setwidth:(id)strokeWidth
                                   setColor:(id)strokeColor{

NSMutableAttributedString* attributeSuits = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:suitString];
if ([strokeWidth isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]&&[strokeWidth isKindOfClass:[UIColor class]]) // error 1 - use of undeclared identifier "UIColor", did you mean '_color'?

{
    [attributeSuits addAttributes:@{NSStrokeWidthAttributeName:strokeWidth, // error 2 - use of undeclared identifier "NSStrokeWidthAttributeName"
                                 NSStrokeColorAttributeName:strokeColor} //// error 3 - use of undeclared identifier "NSStrokeColorAttributeName"
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, suitString.length)];

}

return attributeSuits;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three symbols giving you the error are from UIKit. So this means you are not importing UIKit at the top of the .m file.

Add either

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

or

```
@import UIKit;
```

to the top of the .m file.

It also make no sense that you use `id` for the `strokeWidth` and `strokeColor`. And it makes even less sense to see if `strokeWidth` is an `NSString`. Especially since the `NSStrokeWidthAttributeName` key expects an `NSNumber`. I strongly suggest you change your code to be like this:

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString *)setAttributedSuits:(NSString *)suitString width:(CGFloat)strokeWidth color:(UIColor *)strokeColor {
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
        NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : @(strokeWidth),
        NSStrokeColorAttributeName : strokeColor
    };

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributeSuits = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:suitString attributes:attributes];

    return attributeSuits;
}
```

Of course you need to update the declaration in the .h file to match.

Comment: thanks rmaddy for your advice, it works fine now. I am very new to programming, any suggestions for improve my codes above? very appreciate